# Python-Why does different Tk labels appear as same coordinate and as different objects?

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, tk-toolkit

I tried to create some `Label` subclass in Python to tell you its x and y coordinates. However, when I queried *any* label, it would always return `(1,1)`, even though the Tk objects are different. For example, I clicked the `(2,2)` and `(4,5)` labels, the output:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
============================== RESTART: C:/program.py==============================
(1, 1)
.53825904

(1, 1)
.53826736

>>>
```

X and Y are the same, even though objects are different! (OK, I might have clicked a different coordinate, but what's to care is that the labels are *not on the same coordinate*)

Here is the faulty code:

```
try:
    from tkinter import * # Py3
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import * # Py2

class _MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
    def grid(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        super().grid(row=y, column=x)
    def location(self):
        return (7 - x + 1, 7 - y + 1)

def gen():
    pass

def check(event):
    print(event.widget.location())
    print(event.widget)
    print()

root = Tk()
sqs = [[_MyLabel(root, height=1, width=2, relief=SUNKEN, bg='white') for i in range(8)] for i in range(8)]
seq = []
for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        sqs[y][x].grid(x, y)
        sqs[y][x].bind('<Button-1>', check)


mainloop()
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.x` and `self.y` in `location()` instead of `x` and `y`. I will spare you an explanation because I guess you just overlooked it.